# Heat equation with discontinuous sink and zero flux boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following problem:

$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}=D\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial r^2}-\lambda p,$

on the domain $r\in[0,r_w]$ and for times $t\in [0,\infty)$, where

$ {\displaystyle \lambda={\begin{cases}\lambda_s,& \text{for } 0<r\leq r_s,
\\ \lambda_w,& \text{for } r_s<r\leq r_w.\end{cases}}}$

The initial condition is a dirac delta function at the right hand end of the domain

$p(r,0)=\delta(r-r_w),$

and the boundary conditions are zero flux at either end of the domain:

$\frac{\partial p}{\partial r}|_{r=0}=0$ and $\frac{\partial p}{\partial r}|_{r=r_w}=0$.

At the intermediate boundary I would like continuity and smoothness of the solution:

$p_I(r_s)=p_O(r_s)$,

and

$\frac{\partial p_I}{\partial r}|_{r=r_s}=\frac{\partial p_O}{\partial r}|_{r=r_s}$,

where $p_I$ and $p_O$ are the inner and outer solutions respectively.

If there is a reason why these can't be satisfied, I would be interested to hear why.

I have tried fourier series solutions for the two distinct parts of the domain but couldn't get the matching correct. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Alternatively if the full time dependent solution is too difficult I'd be happy if anyone could solve the time-integrated version of the problem.

$-\delta(r−rw)=D\frac{d^2 \bar{p}}{d r^2}-\lambda \bar{p},$
on the domain $r\in[0,r_w]$, 
where

$ {\displaystyle \lambda={\begin{cases}\lambda_s,& \text{for } 0<r\leq r_s,
\\ \lambda_w,& \text{for } r_s<r\leq r_w,\end{cases}}}$ and $\bar{p}(x)=\int_0^{\infty}p(x,t)dt$ and the boundary conditions are

$\frac{d \bar{p}}{d r}|_{r=0}=0$ and $\frac{d p}{d r}|_{r=r_w}=0$.

Comment: What is the physical situation you are describing?

Comment: The physical context could be a number of different things. It could be a unit of heat energy introduced at the boundary of one dimensional pipe which is insulated at either end, but leaky across its length so that heat energy is lost, but as different rates in different parts of the pipe. Alternatively it could the probability density function for the position of a  particle which diffuses in a one dimensional region with zero-flux boundary conditions and degrades spontaneously, with different rates depending on where it is in the region. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes that does, however i was more interested in the intermediate boundary.  May i assume for the time being that the function should be smooth over this boundary.  At the moment i don't belive you can solve the system without any intermediate BC's.

Comment: I think i may have determined why you can't get the matching correct. I'll post an 'answer' shortly

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have specified. Two matching conditions at the intermediate boundary, continuity and smoothness. I will add this specification to the original problem so that other users can get a full grasp of the problem. I will be interested to hear your thoughts on it.

Answer (score 5):

**Part I**

My ‘answer’ – which admittedly doesn’t solve the system, will be in two parts.  This first part will derive the classical solution for the simpler problem of a single domain using the method of Fokas’ Universal Transform.  The reason for this is that the method makes it very apparent when a problem is ill-posed.  The second part will contain a discussion of the problem for the composite domains.
Consider 
$${{p}_{T}}=D{{p}_{r,r}}-\lambda p\\ \\\lambda =\left\{ \begin{matrix}
   {{\lambda }_{s}} & 0<r\le s  \\
   {{\lambda }_{w}} & s<r\le w  \\
\end{matrix} \right.$$ with zero flux conditions ${{\left. \frac{\partial p}{\partial r} \right|}_{r=0,w}}=0$ and initial condition $q\left( r,0 \right)={{q}_{0}}\left( r \right)$.

Let  $p=\frac{{{w}^{2}}}{D}u,\,\,t=\frac{D}{{{w}^{2}}}T,\,\,x=\frac{r}{w},\,\,{{\lambda }_{-}}=\frac{{{w}^{2}}}{D}{{\lambda }_{s}},\,\,\,{{\lambda }_{+}}=\frac{{{w}^{2}}}{D}{{\lambda }_{w}}$.  Then

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}u}{\partial {{x}^{2}}}-{{\lambda }_{\pm }}u$  where ${{\lambda }_{\pm }}=\left\{ \begin{matrix}
   {{\lambda }_{-}} & 0<x\le {{x}_{s}}  \\
   {{\lambda }_{+}} & {{x}_{s}}<x\le 1  \\
\end{matrix} \right.$  and ${{\left. \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right|}_{x=0,1}}=0$, $u\left( x,0 \right)={{u}_{0}}\left( r \right)$

First let us solve here the problem without the intermediate boundary.  That is assume one value for ${{\lambda }_{\pm }}$over the domain $x\in \left[ 0,1 \right]$.

Let 
$$\hat{u}\left( -ik,t \right)=\int\limits_{0}^{1}{{{e}^{-ikx}}u\left( x,t \right)dx},k\in \mathbb{C}$$
Now
$${{\hat{u}}_{t}}\left( -ik,t \right)=\int\limits_{0}^{1}{{{e}^{-ikx}}{{u}_{t}}\left( x,t \right)dx}=\int\limits_{0}^{1}{{{e}^{-ikx}}\left( {{u}_{xx}}\left( x,t \right)-{{\lambda }_{\pm }}u \right)dx}$$
Integration by parts twice yields
$${{\hat{u}}_{t}}\left( -ik,t \right)+\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)\hat{u}\left( -ik,t \right)={{e}^{-ik}}{{u}_{x}}\left( 1,t \right)+ik{{e}^{-ik}}u\left( 1,t \right)-\left( {{u}_{x}}\left( 0,t \right)+iku\left( 0,t \right) \right)$$
Which we may write as
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\hat{u}\left( -ik,t \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}=\left( {{e}^{-ik}}{{u}_{x}}\left( 1,t \right)+ik{{e}^{-ik}}u\left( 1,t \right)-\left( {{u}_{x}}\left( 0,t \right)+iku\left( 0,t \right) \right) \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}$$
Integrating we find
$$\hat{u}\left( -ik,t \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}-\hat{u}\left( -ik,0 \right)=\int\limits_{0}^{t}{\left( \left( {{u}_{x}}\left( 1,y \right)+iku\left( 1,y \right) \right){{e}^{-ik}}-\left( {{u}_{x}}\left( 0,y \right)+iku\left( 0,y \right) \right) \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)y}}dy}$$
Define
$$\int\limits_{0}^{t}{\left( {{u}_{x}}\left( 0,y \right)+iku\left( 0,y \right) \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)y}}dy}={{\tilde{g}}_{1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)+ik{{\tilde{g}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)$$
$$\int\limits_{0}^{t}{\left( {{u}_{x}}\left( 1,y \right)+iku\left( 1,y \right) \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)y-ik}}dy}={{e}^{-ik}}\left( {{{\tilde{h}}}_{1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)+ik{{{\tilde{h}}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right) \right)$$
Where the subscript of ‘0’ pertains to the Dirichlet boundary conditions (non-derivatives) and ‘1’ to the Neumann conditions (derivatives).  We have what Fokas labels the global relation
$$\hat{u}\left( -ik,t \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}-\hat{u}\left( -ik,0 \right)=\left( {{{\tilde{h}}}_{1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)+ik{{{\tilde{h}}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right) \right){{e}^{-ik}}-\left( {{{\tilde{g}}}_{1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)+ik{{{\tilde{g}}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right) \right)$$
Taking the inverse fourier transform we obtain
$$u\left( x,t \right)=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }{\hat{u}\left( -ik,0 \right){{e}^{ikx-\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}dk}-\frac{1}{2\pi }\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }{\left( {{{\tilde{g}}}_{1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)+ik{{{\tilde{g}}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right) \right){{e}^{ikx-\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}dk}+\frac{1}{2\pi }\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }{\left( {{{\tilde{h}}}_{1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)+ik{{{\tilde{h}}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right) \right){{e}^{ik\left( 1-x \right)-\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}dk}$$
Now $x\le 1$ and $y\le t$ then for the last two integrals to be bounded as $\left| k \right|\to \infty $ we have upon considering the terms in those integrals, the following requirements on k:
$${{I}_{2}}:{{e}^{i\operatorname{Re}\left( k \right)x-i\operatorname{Im}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)\left( t-y \right)-\operatorname{Im}\left( k \right)x-\operatorname{Re}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)\left( t-y \right)+{{\lambda }_{\pm }}\left( y-t \right)}}\Rightarrow \operatorname{Im}\left( k \right)\ge 0,\operatorname{Re}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)\ge 0$$
$${{I}_{3}}:{{e}^{i\operatorname{Re}\left( k \right)\left( x-1 \right)-i\operatorname{Im}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)\left( t-y \right)+Im\left( k \right)\left( 1-x \right)-\operatorname{Re}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)\left( t-y \right)-{{\lambda }_{\pm }}\left( t-y \right)}}\Rightarrow Im\left( k \right)\le 0\,\,\operatorname{Re}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)\ge 0$$
where the integrals have been labelled 1,2,3 (left to right).
Note that $$\operatorname{Re}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)=\operatorname{Re}\left( r_{k}^{2}{{e}^{i2{{\theta }_{k}}}} \right)\Rightarrow \cos \left( 2{{\theta }_{k}} \right)\ge 0$$.  Hence
$${{\theta }_{k}}\in \left[ -\frac{\pi }{4},\frac{\pi }{4} \right]\cup \left[ \frac{3\pi }{4},\frac{5\pi }{4} \right]$$
Couple this requirement with the additional requirements for convergence and we find the regions in the complex plane where the functions within the integrals are analytic and bounded as $\left| k \right|\to \infty $.  Namely
$${{I}_{2}}:\operatorname{Im}\left( k \right)\ge 0,\operatorname{Re}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)\ge 0\Rightarrow {{\theta }_{k}}\in \left[ 0,\frac{\pi }{4} \right]\cup \left[ \frac{3\pi }{4},\pi  \right]$$ (region bounded by $\partial {{D}_{+}}$) 
$${{I}_{3}}:Im\left( k \right)\le 0\,\,\operatorname{Re}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)\ge 0\Rightarrow {{\theta }_{k}}\in \left[ -\frac{\pi }{4},0 \right]\cup \left[ \pi ,\frac{5\pi }{4} \right]$$ (region bounded by $\partial {{D}_{-}}$)

[image]

Note the orientation of the boundaries $\partial {{D}_{\pm }}$are chosen to be positive with respect to the shaded region.  Note also that the functions within the integrals are analytic and bounded within the non-shaded regions.  By cauchy’s theorem and Jordan’s lemma  (i.e. consider for each region two circular arcs joining the real line to the boundary D…the function goes to zero on these arcs)  we may deform the real line into a contour within the above stated regions.  That is for example
 $${{I}_{2}}:\int\limits_{-R}^{R}{{}}+\int\limits_{CR1}^{{}}{{}}+\int\limits_{CR2}^{{}}{{}}-\int\limits_{\partial {{D}_{+}}}^{{}}{{}}=0\Rightarrow \int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }{{}}=\int\limits_{\partial {{D}_{+}}}^{{}}{{}}$$  in the limit $R\to \infty $ 
where C1 and C2 are the two circular arcs closing the contour, on which the function approach zero in the limit as their radius becomes infinite.  A similar argument applies for ${{I}_{3}}$, i.e.
$${{I}_{3}}:-\int\limits_{-R}^{R}{{}}+\int\limits_{CR1}^{{}}{{}}+\int\limits_{CR2}^{{}}{{}}-\int\limits_{\partial {{D}_{+}}}^{{}}{{}}=0\Rightarrow \int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }{{}}=-\int\limits_{\partial {{D}_{-}}}^{{}}{{}}$$ in the limit $R\to \infty $.  Hence
$$\begin{align}
  & u\left( x,t \right)=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }{\hat{u}\left( -ik,0 \right){{e}^{ikx-\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}dk} \\ 
 & -\frac{1}{2\pi }\int\limits_{\partial {{D}_{+}}}^{{}}{\left( {{{\tilde{g}}}_{1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)+ik{{{\tilde{g}}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right) \right){{e}^{ikx-\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}dk}-\frac{1}{2\pi }\int\limits_{\partial {{D}_{-}}}^{{}}{\left( {{{\tilde{h}}}_{1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)+ik{{{\tilde{h}}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right) \right){{e}^{ik\left( x-1 \right)-\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}dk} \\ 
\end{align}$$
This is the general solution to the problem.  We now examine specific boundary conditions and initial conditions.  Note we have ${{u}_{x}}\left( 0,t \right)={{u}_{x}}\left( 1,t \right)=0$ and so ${{\tilde{g}}_{1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)=0$ and ${{\tilde{h}}_{1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)=0$.  The global relation becomes therefore 
$$\hat{u}\left( -ik,t \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}-\hat{u}\left( -ik,0 \right)=ik{{\tilde{h}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right){{e}^{-ik}}-ik{{\tilde{g}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)$$
One equation and two unknowns.  However letting $k\to -k$ we have
$$\hat{u}\left( ik,t \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}-\hat{u}\left( ik,0 \right)=-ik{{\tilde{h}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right){{e}^{ik}}+ik{{\tilde{g}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)$$
Therefore the system of equations is
$$\left[ \begin{matrix}
   \hat{u}\left( -ik,t \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}-\hat{u}\left( -ik,0 \right)  \\
   \hat{u}\left( ik,t \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}-\hat{u}\left( ik,0 \right)  \\
\end{matrix} \right]=\left[ \begin{matrix}
   ik{{e}^{-ik}} & -ik  \\
   -ik{{e}^{ik}} & ik  \\
\end{matrix} \right]\left[ \begin{matrix}
   {{{\tilde{h}}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)  \\
   {{{\tilde{g}}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)  \\
\end{matrix} \right]$$

Inverting we have
$$\frac{ik}{{{k}^{2}}\left( {{e}^{ik}}-{{e}^{-ik}} \right)}\left[ \begin{matrix}
   1 & 1  \\
   {{e}^{ik}} & {{e}^{-ik}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right]\left[ \begin{matrix}
   \hat{u}\left( -ik,t \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}-\hat{u}\left( -ik,0 \right)  \\
   \hat{u}\left( ik,t \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}-\hat{u}\left( ik,0 \right)  \\
\end{matrix} \right]=\left[ \begin{matrix}
   {{{\tilde{h}}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)  \\
   {{{\tilde{g}}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)  \\
\end{matrix} \right]$$

hence

$$\begin{align}
  & {{{\tilde{h}}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)=\frac{i}{k\left( {{e}^{ik}}-{{e}^{-ik}} \right)}\left( \left( \hat{u}\left( -ik,t \right)+\hat{u}\left( ik,t \right) \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}-\left( \hat{u}\left( -ik,0 \right)+\hat{u}\left( ik,0 \right) \right) \right) \\ 
 & {{{\tilde{g}}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)=\frac{i}{k\left( {{e}^{ik}}-{{e}^{-ik}} \right)}\left( \left( \hat{u}\left( -ik,t \right){{e}^{ik}}+\hat{u}\left( ik,t \right){{e}^{-ik}} \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}-\left( \hat{u}\left( -ik,0 \right){{e}^{ik}}+\hat{u}\left( ik,0 \right){{e}^{-ik}} \right) \right) \\ 
\end{align}$$
The solution is therefore

$$\begin{align}
  & u\left( x,t \right)=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }{\hat{u}\left( -ik,0 \right){{e}^{ikx-\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}dk} \\ 
 & +\frac{1}{2\pi }\int\limits_{\partial {{D}_{+}}}^{{}}{\left( \frac{1}{\left( {{e}^{ik}}-{{e}^{-ik}} \right)}\left( \left( \hat{u}\left( -ik,t \right){{e}^{ik}}+\hat{u}\left( ik,t \right){{e}^{-ik}} \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}\\-\left( \hat{u}\left( -ik,0 \right){{e}^{ik}}+\hat{u}\left( ik,0 \right){{e}^{-ik}} \right) \right) \right){{e}^{ikx-\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}dk} \\ 
 & +\frac{1}{2\pi }\int\limits_{\partial {{D}_{-}}}^{{}}{\left( \frac{1}{\left( {{e}^{ik}}-{{e}^{-ik}} \right)}\left( \left( \hat{u}\left( -ik,t \right)+\hat{u}\left( ik,t \right) \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}\\-\left( \hat{u}\left( -ik,0 \right)+\hat{u}\left( ik,0 \right) \right) \right) \right){{e}^{ik\left( x-1 \right)-\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}dk} \\ 
\end{align}$$

Based on $\hat{u}\left( -ik,t \right)$ being analytic and $\hat{u}\left( -ik,t \right)\to 0$ uniformly as $k\to \infty $ then the first terms in the last two integrals make no contribution along the contour (we can deform the contours to avoid any possible singularity at k=0 if needs be, and close them around the shaded regions with single arc composed of a large radius heading to infinity.  Cauchy’s theorem then implies the contour integral is zero, and Jordan’s lemma implies the integral over the radial arc approaches zero in the limit).  Hence
$$\begin{align}
  & u\left( x,t \right)=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }{\hat{u}\left( -ik,0 \right){{e}^{ikx-\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}dk} \\ 
 & -\frac{1}{2\pi }\int\limits_{\partial {{D}_{+}}}^{{}}{\frac{1}{\left( {{e}^{ik}}-{{e}^{-ik}} \right)}\left( \hat{u}\left( -ik,0 \right){{e}^{ik}}+\hat{u}\left( ik,0 \right){{e}^{-ik}} \right){{e}^{ikx-\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}dk} \\ 
 & -\frac{1}{2\pi }\int\limits_{\partial {{D}_{-}}}^{{}}{\frac{1}{\left( {{e}^{ik}}-{{e}^{-ik}} \right)}\left( \hat{u}\left( -ik,0 \right)+\hat{u}\left( ik,0 \right) \right){{e}^{ik\left( x-1 \right)-\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}dk} \\ 
\end{align}$$
We now deform the contour to the real line to obtain the classical solution. Consider the $\partial {{D}_{+}}$ which we will deform back to the real line in the following manner:  As done previously add to $\partial {{D}_{+}}$ two circular arcs of radius R, however also add 2N semicircular arcs that avoid the poles on the real axis, i.e. ${{k}_{n}}=n\pi $ , along with the segments between these arcs.  We have 
$$\int\limits_{C}^{{}}{{}}=\sum\limits_{n=-N}^{N}{{}}\int\limits_{{{\delta }_{n}}}^{{}}{{}}+\sum\limits_{n=-N}^{N}{\int\limits_{{{x}_{n}}}^{{{x}_{n+1}}}{{}}}+\int\limits_{{{R}_{1}}}^{{}}{{}}+\int\limits_{{{R}_{2}}}^{{}}{{}}-\int\limits_{\partial {{D}^{+}}}^{{}}{{}}=0$$

The contributions on the two arcs go to zero as $R\to \infty $ , and the integrals around the semi-circles are $-\pi i$ times the residue of the poles.  Hence we have 
$$\int\limits_{\partial {{D}^{+}}}^{{}}{{}}=-\pi i\sum\limits_{n=-\infty }^{\infty }{re{{s}_{\partial {{D}^{+}}}}}+pv\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }{{}}$$
Similarly for the other contour we have
$$\int\limits_{C}^{{}}{{}}=\sum\limits_{n=-N}^{N}{{}}\int\limits_{{{\delta }_{n}}}^{{}}{{}}+\sum\limits_{n=-N}^{N}{{}}\int\limits_{{{x}_{n}}}^{{{x}_{n+1}}}{{}}-\int\limits_{{{R}_{1}}}^{{}}{{}}-\int\limits_{{{R}_{2}}}^{{}}{{}}+\int\limits_{\partial {{D}^{-}}}^{{}}{{}}=0$$
$$\int\limits_{\partial {{D}^{-}}}^{{}}{{}}=-\pi i\sum\limits_{n=-\infty }^{\infty }{re{{s}_{\partial {{D}^{-}}}}}-pv\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }{{}}$$

The residues may be calculated as follows using $\underset{z={{z}_{o}}}{\mathop{\operatorname{Re}s}}\,\,\,\frac{f\left( z \right)}{g\left( z \right)}=\underset{z={{z}_{o}}}{\mathop{\lim }}\,\frac{f\left( z \right)}{g'\left( z \right)}$ for simple poles
$$res\frac{1}{\left( {{e}^{ik}}-{{e}^{-ik}} \right)}=\frac{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{n}}}{2i}$$
$$re{{s}_{\partial {{D}_{+}}}}={{\left( -1 \right)}^{n}}\frac{1}{4\pi i}\left( \hat{u}\left( -i{{k}_{n}},0 \right){{e}^{i{{k}_{n}}}}+\hat{u}\left( i{{k}_{n}},0 \right){{e}^{-i{{k}_{n}}}} \right){{e}^{in\pi x-\left( {{n}^{2}}{{\pi }^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}$$
$$re{{s}_{\partial {{D}_{-}}}}={{\left( -1 \right)}^{n}}\frac{1}{4\pi i}\left( \hat{u}\left( -i{{k}_{n}},0 \right)+\hat{u}\left( i{{k}_{n}},0 \right) \right){{e}^{in\pi \left( x-1 \right)-\left( {{n}^{2}}{{\pi }^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}$$ 
Note: $$re{{s}_{\partial {{D}_{+}}}}=re{{s}_{\partial {{D}_{-}}}}$$
Now
$$\hat{u}\left( -i{{k}_{n}},0 \right)+\hat{u}\left( i{{k}_{n}},0 \right)=2\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\cos \left( {{k}_{n}}y \right){{u}_{0}}\left( y \right)dy}$$
So for example
$$re{{s}_{\partial {{D}_{+}}}}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}{{e}^{in\pi x-\left( {{n}^{2}}{{\pi }^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\cos \left( {{k}_{n}}y \right){{u}_{0}}\left( y \right)dy}$$
We have then
$$\begin{align}
  & u\left( x,t \right)=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }{\hat{u}\left( -ik,0 \right){{e}^{ikx-\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}dk} \\ 
 & +2\pi i\sum\limits_{n=-\infty }^{\infty }{re{{s}_{\partial {{D}_{+}}}}}-pv\frac{1}{2\pi }\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }{\frac{1}{\left( {{e}^{ik}}-{{e}^{-ik}} \right)}\left( \hat{u}\left( -ik,0 \right){{e}^{ik}}+\hat{u}\left( ik,0 \right){{e}^{-ik}} \right){{e}^{ikx-\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}dk} \\ 
 & +pv\frac{1}{2\pi }\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }{\frac{1}{\left( {{e}^{ik}}-{{e}^{-ik}} \right)}\left( \hat{u}\left( -ik,0 \right)+\hat{u}\left( ik,0 \right) \right){{e}^{ik\left( x-1 \right)-\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}dk} \\ 
\end{align}$$
Simplifying yields 
$$u\left( x,t \right)=2\pi i\sum\limits_{n=-\infty }^{\infty }{re{{s}_{\partial {{D}_{+}}}}}$$
(note that the two principal value integrals combine to cancel the initial condition integral).  Therefore we have
$$u\left( x,t \right)=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty }^{\infty }{{{e}^{in\pi x-\left( {{n}^{2}}{{\pi }^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\cos \left( {{k}_{n}}y \right){{u}_{0}}\left( y \right)dy}}$$
$$u\left( x,t \right)={{e}^{-{{\lambda }_{\pm }}t}}\int\limits_{0}^{1}{{{u}_{0}}\left( y \right)dy}+2\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }{\cos \left( n\pi x \right){{e}^{-\left( {{n}^{2}}{{\pi }^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{\pm }} \right)t}}\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\cos \left( n\pi y \right){{u}_{0}}\left( y \right)dy}}$$

This is the classical solution for the simplified problem of a single domain.  Note that in using this method it becomes very clear as to which unknown boundary conditions can / cannot be eliminated, leading to a system that can / cannot be solved.  We will make use of this fact in the second part.

Answer (score 5):

**Part II**

Proceeding now with the actual problem.  We define two functions over the two domains,
${{u}_{-}}\left( x,t \right),0\le x\le {{x}_{s}}$and ${{u}_{+}}\left( x,t \right),{{x}_{s}}<x\le 1$.  Then proceeding as we did before we find 
$${{\hat{u}}_{-t}}\left( -ik,t \right)+\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{-}} \right){{\hat{u}}_{-}}\left( -ik,t \right)=\left( {{u}_{-x}}\left( {{x}_{s}},t \right)+ik{{u}_{-}}\left( {{x}_{s}},t \right) \right){{e}^{-ik{{x}_{s}}}}-\left( {{u}_{-x}}\left( 0,t \right)+ik{{u}_{-}}\left( 0,t \right) \right)$$
$${{\hat{u}}_{+t}}\left( -ik,t \right)+\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{+}} \right){{\hat{u}}_{+}}\left( -ik,t \right)=\left( {{u}_{+x}}\left( 1,t \right)+ik{{u}_{+}}\left( 1,t \right) \right){{e}^{-ik}}-\left( {{u}_{+x}}\left( {{x}_{s}},t \right)+ik{{u}_{+}}\left( {{x}_{s}},t \right) \right){{e}^{-ik{{x}_{s}}}}$$
Writing the LHS as a derivative, then integrating we have
$${{\hat{u}}_{-}}\left( -ik,t \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{-}} \right)t}}-{{\hat{u}}_{-}}\left( -ik,0 \right)=\int\limits_{0}^{t}{\left( {{u}_{-x}}\left( {{x}_{s}},y \right)+ik{{u}_{-}}\left( {{x}_{s}},y \right) \right){{e}^{-ik{{x}_{s}}+\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{-}} \right)y}}-\left( {{u}_{-x}}\left( 0,y \right)+ik{{u}_{-}}\left( 0,y \right) \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{-}} \right)y}}dy}$$
$${{\hat{u}}_{+}}\left( -ik,t \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{+}} \right)t}}-{{\hat{u}}_{+}}\left( -ik,0 \right)=\int\limits_{0}^{t}{\left( {{u}_{+x}}\left( 1,y \right)+ik{{u}_{+}}\left( 1,y \right) \right){{e}^{-ik+\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{+}} \right)y}}-\left( {{u}_{+x}}\left( {{x}_{s}},y \right)+ik{{u}_{+}}\left( {{x}_{s}},y \right) \right){{e}^{-ik{{x}_{s}}+\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{+}} \right)y}}dy}$$
As done previously we define the following functions by writing the above equations as
$${{\hat{u}}_{-}}\left( -ik,t \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{-}} \right)t}}-{{\hat{u}}_{-}}\left( -ik,0 \right)=\left( {{{\tilde{j}}}_{-1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)+ik{{{\tilde{j}}}_{-0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right) \right){{e}^{-ik{{x}_{s}}}}-\left( {{{\tilde{g}}}_{1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)+ik{{{\tilde{g}}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right) \right)$$
$${{\hat{u}}_{+}}\left( -ik,t \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{+}} \right)t}}-{{\hat{u}}_{+}}\left( -ik,0 \right)=\left( {{{\tilde{h}}}_{1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)+ik{{{\tilde{h}}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right) \right){{e}^{-ik}}-\left( {{{\tilde{j}}}_{+1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)+ik{{{\tilde{j}}}_{+0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right) \right){{e}^{-ik{{x}_{s}}}}$$
The j-functions represent the boundary value data for the intermediate layer.
Inverting the transform and deforming the integrals to a contour off the real line (the boundaries/regions are the same as before) we have
$$\begin{align}
  & {{u}_{-}}\left( x,t \right)=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }{{{{\hat{u}}}_{-}}\left( -ik,0 \right){{e}^{ikx-\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{-}} \right)t}}dk} \\ 
 & -\frac{1}{2\pi }\int\limits_{\partial {{D}^{+}}}^{{}}{\left( {{{\tilde{g}}}_{1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)+ik{{{\tilde{g}}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right) \right){{e}^{ikx-\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{-}} \right)t}}dk}-\frac{1}{2\pi }\int\limits_{\partial {{D}^{-}}}^{{}}{\left( {{{\tilde{j}}}_{-1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)+ik{{{\tilde{j}}}_{-0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right) \right){{e}^{ikx-ik{{x}_{s}}-\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{-}} \right)t}}dk} \\ 
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
  & {{u}_{+}}\left( x,t \right)=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }{{{{\hat{u}}}_{+}}\left( -ik,0 \right){{e}^{ikx-\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{-}} \right)t}}} \\ 
 & -\frac{1}{2\pi }\int\limits_{\partial {{D}^{+}}}^{{}}{\left( {{{\tilde{j}}}_{+1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)+ik{{{\tilde{j}}}_{+0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right) \right){{e}^{ikx-ik{{x}_{s}}-\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{+}} \right)t}}dk}+\frac{1}{2\pi }\int\limits_{\partial {{D}^{-}}}^{{}}{\left( {{{\tilde{h}}}_{1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)+ik{{{\tilde{h}}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right) \right){{e}^{ikx-ik-\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{+}} \right)t}}dk} \\ 
\end{align}$$
At the moment we have eight transformed boundary value points and only two equations. The symmetry in the unknown transformed boundary data allows us to map $k\to -k$ , which then yields four equations.  Substituting known boundary conditions $${{\tilde{g}}_{1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)={{\tilde{h}}_{1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)=0$$eliminates two unknowns and so we have 6 unknowns and four equations.  Two more conditions are required.
Note from the differential equation for either function we have
$\frac{\partial {{u}_{\pm }}}{\partial t}=\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}{{u}_{\pm }}}{\partial {{x}^{2}}}-{{\lambda }_{\pm }}{{u}_{\pm }}\Rightarrow \frac{\partial }{\partial t}\int\limits_{{{x}_{s}}-\varepsilon }^{{{x}_{s}}+\varepsilon }{{{u}_{\pm }}dx}={{\left. \frac{\partial {{u}_{+}}}{\partial x} \right|}_{{{x}_{s}}+\varepsilon }}-{{\left. \frac{\partial {{u}_{-}}}{\partial x} \right|}_{{{x}_{s}}-\varepsilon }}-{{\lambda }_{\pm }}\int\limits_{{{x}_{s}}-\varepsilon }^{{{x}_{s}}+\varepsilon }{{{u}_{\pm }}dx}$
If the function is ‘well-behaved’ on the boundary then the integrals go to zero as epsilon goes to zero and we have 
${{\left. \frac{\partial {{u}_{+}}}{\partial x} \right|}_{{{x}_{s}}}}={{\left. \frac{\partial {{u}_{-}}}{\partial x} \right|}_{{{x}_{s}}}}$ 
Note that for example we have therefore 
$${{\tilde{j}}_{+1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)=\int\limits_{0}^{t}{{{u}_{+x}}\left( {{x}_{s}},y \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{+}} \right)y}}dy}=\int\limits_{0}^{t}{{{u}_{-x}}\left( {{x}_{s}},y \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{+}} \right)y}}dy}\ne {{\tilde{j}}_{-1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right),{{\tilde{j}}_{+0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right),{{\tilde{j}}_{-0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)$$
And so this in no way allows us to eliminate an unknown unless ${{\lambda }_{+}}={{\lambda }_{-}}$, in which case ${{\tilde{j}}_{+1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)={{\tilde{j}}_{-1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)$.  But obviously we don’t want this.   A similar situation exists if we insist that the ‘temperatures’ on the boundary are the same, i.e. ${{u}_{+}}\left( {{x}_{s}},y \right)={{u}_{-}}\left( {{x}_{s}},y \right)$, in that this conditions won’t allow for the elimination of  ${{\tilde{j}}_{+0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)$ or ${{\tilde{j}}_{-0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)$ .
Note however that if we insist ${{u}_{+x}}\left( {{x}_{s}},t \right)={{e}^{\left( {{\lambda }_{-}}-{{\lambda }_{+}} \right)t}}{{u}_{-x}}\left( {{x}_{s}},t \right)$, and ${{u}_{+}}\left( {{x}_{s}},t \right)={{e}^{\left( {{\lambda }_{-}}-{{\lambda }_{+}} \right)t}}{{u}_{-}}\left( {{x}_{s}},t \right)$ then we can eliminate two more unknowns, for note:
$${{\tilde{j}}_{+1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)=\int\limits_{0}^{t}{{{u}_{+x}}\left( {{x}_{s}},y \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{+}} \right)y}}dy}=\int\limits_{0}^{t}{{{u}_{-x}}\left( {{x}_{s}},y \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{-}} \right)y}}dy}={{\tilde{j}}_{-1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)$$
$${{\tilde{j}}_{+0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)=\int\limits_{0}^{t}{{{u}_{+}}\left( {{x}_{s}},y \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{+}} \right)y}}dy}=\int\limits_{0}^{t}{{{u}_{-}}\left( {{x}_{s}},y \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{-}} \right)y}}dy}={{\tilde{j}}_{-0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)$$
But as we will see, the solution this generates has problems, and so therefore the assumed intermediate boundary conditions appear invalid with respect to the system.  However for now let us proceed with these assumptions. Doing so we have four equations and four unknowns.
$${{\hat{u}}_{-}}\left( -ik,t \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{-}} \right)t}}-{{\hat{u}}_{-}}\left( -ik,0 \right)=\left( {{{\tilde{j}}}_{1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)+ik{{{\tilde{j}}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right) \right){{e}^{-ik{{x}_{s}}}}-ik{{\tilde{g}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)$$
$${{\hat{u}}_{+}}\left( -ik,t \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{+}} \right)t}}-{{\hat{u}}_{+}}\left( -ik,0 \right)=ik{{\tilde{h}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right){{e}^{-ik}}-\left( {{{\tilde{j}}}_{1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)+ik{{{\tilde{j}}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right) \right){{e}^{-ik{{x}_{s}}}}$$
$${{\hat{u}}_{-}}\left( ik,t \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{-}} \right)t}}-{{\hat{u}}_{-}}\left( ik,0 \right)=\left( {{{\tilde{j}}}_{1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)-ik{{{\tilde{j}}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right) \right){{e}^{ik{{x}_{s}}}}+ik{{\tilde{g}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)$$
$${{\hat{u}}_{+}}\left( ik,t \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{+}} \right)t}}-{{\hat{u}}_{+}}\left( ik,0 \right)=-ik{{\tilde{h}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right){{e}^{ik}}-\left( {{{\tilde{j}}}_{1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)-ik{{{\tilde{j}}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right) \right){{e}^{ik{{x}_{s}}}}$$
 Solving this system of equations we find
$${{\tilde{g}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)=\frac{i}{k\left( {{e}^{2ik}}-1 \right)}\left( \begin{align}
  & -{{e}^{2ik}}\left( {{{\hat{u}}}_{-}}\left( -ik,0 \right)+{{{\hat{u}}}_{+}}\left( -ik,0 \right) \right)-\left( {{{\hat{u}}}_{-}}\left( ik,0 \right)+{{{\hat{u}}}_{+}}\left( ik,0 \right) \right) \\ 
 & +\left( {{e}^{2ik}}{{{\hat{u}}}_{-}}\left( -ik,t \right)+{{{\hat{u}}}_{-}}\left( ik,t \right) \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{-}} \right)t}}+\left( {{e}^{2ik}}{{{\hat{u}}}_{+}}\left( -ik,t \right)+{{{\hat{u}}}_{+}}\left( ik,t \right) \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{+}} \right)t}} \\ 
\end{align} \right)$$
$${{\tilde{h}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)=\frac{i{{e}^{ik}}}{k\left( {{e}^{2ik}}-1 \right)}\left( \begin{align}
  & -\left( {{{\hat{u}}}_{-}}\left( -ik,0 \right)+{{{\hat{u}}}_{-}}\left( ik,0 \right)+{{{\hat{u}}}_{+}}\left( -ik,0 \right)+{{{\hat{u}}}_{+}}\left( ik,0 \right) \right) \\ 
 & +\left( {{{\hat{u}}}_{-}}\left( -ik,t \right)+{{{\hat{u}}}_{-}}\left( ik,t \right) \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{-}} \right)t}}+\left( {{{\hat{u}}}_{+}}\left( -ik,t \right)+{{{\hat{u}}}_{+}}\left( ik,t \right) \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{+}} \right)t}} \\ 
\end{align} \right)$$
$${{\tilde{j}}_{0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)=-\frac{i{{e}^{-ik{{x}_{s}}}}}{2k\left( {{e}^{2ik}}-1 \right)}\left( \begin{align}
  & \left( {{{\hat{u}}}_{-}}\left( -ik,0 \right)+{{{\hat{u}}}_{-}}\left( ik,0 \right) \right)\left( {{e}^{2ik}}+{{e}^{2ik{{x}_{s}}}} \right)+\left( {{e}^{2ik}}{{{\hat{u}}}_{+}}\left( -ik,0 \right)+{{{\hat{u}}}_{+}}\left( ik,0 \right) \right)\left( 1+{{e}^{2ik{{x}_{s}}}} \right) \\ 
 & -\left( {{{\hat{u}}}_{-}}\left( -ik,t \right)+{{{\hat{u}}}_{-}}\left( ik,t \right) \right)\left( {{e}^{2ik}}+{{e}^{2ik{{x}_{s}}}} \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{-}} \right)t}}-\left( {{{\hat{u}}}_{+}}\left( -ik,t \right){{e}^{2ik}}+{{{\hat{u}}}_{+}}\left( ik,t \right) \right)\left( 1+{{e}^{2ik{{x}_{s}}}} \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{+}} \right)t}} \\ 
\end{align} \right)$$
$${{\tilde{j}}_{1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)=\frac{{{e}^{-ik{{x}_{s}}}}}{2\left( {{e}^{2ik}}-1 \right)}\left( \begin{align}
  & \left( {{{\hat{u}}}_{-}}\left( -ik,0 \right)+{{{\hat{u}}}_{-}}\left( ik,0 \right) \right)\left( {{e}^{2ik{{x}_{s}}}}-{{e}^{2ik}} \right)+\left( {{{\hat{u}}}_{+}}\left( -ik,0 \right){{e}^{2ik}}+{{{\hat{u}}}_{+}}\left( ik,0 \right) \right)\left( {{e}^{2ik{{x}_{s}}}}-1 \right) \\ 
 & +\left( {{{\hat{u}}}_{-}}\left( -ik,t \right)+{{{\hat{u}}}_{-}}\left( ik,t \right) \right)\left( {{e}^{2ik}}-{{e}^{2ik{{x}_{s}}}} \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{-}} \right)t}}+\left( {{{\hat{u}}}_{+}}\left( -ik,t \right){{e}^{2ik}}+{{{\hat{u}}}_{+}}\left( ik,t \right) \right)\left( 1-{{e}^{2ik{{x}_{s}}}} \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{+}} \right)t}} \\ 
\end{align} \right)$$
All terms involving a factor of ${{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{-}} \right)t}}$ become analytic and bounded in the half planes containing their contours.  Their contribution along their contours therefore becomes zero for arguments similar to those used previously.  Hence we have effectively the following for the j-boundary data,
$${{\tilde{j}}_{+1}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)+ik{{\tilde{j}}_{+0}}\left( {{k}^{2}} \right)=\frac{{{e}^{ik{{x}_{s}}}}}{\left( {{e}^{2ik}}-1 \right)}\left( {{{\hat{u}}}_{-}}\left( -ik,0 \right)+{{{\hat{u}}}_{-}}\left( ik,0 \right)+{{{\hat{u}}}_{+}}\left( -ik,0 \right){{e}^{2ik}}+{{{\hat{u}}}_{+}}\left( ik,0 \right) \right)$$
This however has a factor of ${{e}^{ik{{x}_{s}}}}$ which will cancel the ${{e}^{-ik{{x}_{s}}}}$ term in ${{e}^{ikx-ik{{x}_{s}}-\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{-}} \right)t}}$ within the solution essentially obliterating the boundary.  That is the solution is independent of ${{x}_{s}}$.   This is a problem! However it is easily explaind.  Observe that we may write the PDE in the following way
$\frac{\partial {{U}_{\pm }}}{\partial t}=\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}{{U}_{\pm }}}{\partial {{x}^{2}}},\,\,{{U}_{\pm }}={{u}_{\pm }}{{e}^{{{\lambda }_{\pm }}t}}$
The conditions we are using above effectively imply on the boundary that ${{U}_{+}}\left( {{x}_{s}},t \right)={{U}_{-}}\left( {{x}_{s}},t \right),\,\,{{U}_{x+}}\left( {{x}_{s}},t \right)={{U}_{x-}}\left( {{x}_{s}},t \right)$ , which explains why the boundary point is disappearing.

My assumption is that i am either missing something very obvious (regarding the physical nature of the system i.e. should we even expect this thing to have a solution, or perhaps we should be expecting a weak solution), made a mistake with the solution of the system (I have checked most of it with mathematica - so probably not), or this method can't solve this composite material type of problem (very unlikely).  My guess at this stage is that we perhaps need Robin boundary conditions on the inetermediate layer - for note that such conditions will also allow us to elminate two unknowns.  That was my next step.

Also note that book by M. Necati Ozisik "Boundary value problems of heat conduction" contains various composite material solutions, but interestingly none with two Neumann conditions on the end of the 'slab'.

**Edit:**
I am going to upgrade my assumption to that being the system as stated is ill-posed.  I say this because without the $\lambda $ coeff's the composite system is tractable via this method using the standard boundary conditions at the interface (and so to, i assume, via the standard classical approaches).  The issue boils down to the following four functions

$$\int\limits_{0}^{t}{\left( {{u}_{-x}}\left( {{x}_{s}},y \right)+ik{{u}_{-}}\left( {{x}_{s}},y \right) \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{-}} \right)y}}dy}={{j}_{1-}}\left( {{k}^{2}},{{\lambda }_{-}} \right)+{{j}_{0-}}\left( {{k}^{2}},{{\lambda }_{-}} \right)$$
$$\int\limits_{0}^{t}{\left( {{u}_{+x}}\left( {{x}_{s}},y \right)+ik{{u}_{+}}\left( {{x}_{s}},y \right) \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{+}} \right)y}}dy}={{j}_{1+}}\left( {{k}^{2}},{{\lambda }_{+}} \right)+{{j}_{0+}}\left( {{k}^{2}},{{\lambda }_{+}} \right)$$

What is required is a boundary condition that relates the various u+/- functions so that we can eliminate two of the transformed functions (the j-functions) to obtain a set of four unknowns for the four equations.  The various ways of doing this (as discussed previously in this post) ultimately remove the intermediate layer from the problem. The standard robin-like boundary conditions used in Ozisik for composite media won't work.  For example, consider (Ozisik)
$${{u}_{-x}}\left( {{x}_{s}},t \right)=h\left( {{u}_{-}}\left( {{x}_{s}},t \right)-{{u}_{+}}\left( {{x}_{s}},t \right) \right)$$  and 
$${{u}_{-x}}\left( {{x}_{s}},t \right)={{u}_{+x}}\left( {{x}_{s}},t \right)$$
Where ‘h’ represents a contact conductance
From this we have then
$${{\hat{u}}_{-}}\left( -ik,t \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{-}} \right)t}}-{{\hat{u}}_{-}}\left( -ik,0 \right)=\int\limits_{0}^{t}{\left( -h{{u}_{+}}\left( {{x}_{s}},t \right)+\left( ik+h \right){{u}_{-}}\left( {{x}_{s}},y \right) \right){{e}^{-ik{{x}_{s}}+\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{-}} \right)y}}-ik{{u}_{-}}\left( 0,y \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{-}} \right)y}}dy}$$
$${{\hat{u}}_{+}}\left( -ik,t \right){{e}^{\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{+}} \right)t}}-{{\hat{u}}_{+}}\left( -ik,0 \right)=\int\limits_{0}^{t}{ik{{u}_{+}}\left( 1,y \right){{e}^{-ik+\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{+}} \right)y}}-\left( h{{u}_{-}}\left( {{x}_{s}},t \right)+\left( ik-h \right){{u}_{+}}\left( {{x}_{s}},y \right) \right){{e}^{-ik{{x}_{s}}+\left( {{k}^{2}}+{{\lambda }_{+}} \right)y}}dy}$$
Note that this system is still not well-posed because we still cannot eliminate two unknowns (due to the fact that the integral transforms of the boundary value data are different transforms due to the different $\lambda $ coefficients).  If, however, the $\lambda $ coefficients were equal then it is well posed.  So if we remove the $\lambda $coefficients we can eliminate two of the unknowns and the final solution is one where the interface is present (I won’t provide the calculations unless requested, but it becomes apparent reasonably quickly using Mathematica to do the algebra).

Where to from here depends upon exactly what you are trying to model.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for the hugely detailed answer.

Comment: Your welcome. It is an interesting problem.