# How to take such Fourier transform to solve PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

I am reading [here](http://www.caam.rice.edu/~cox/stoch/lectheobio.pdf) Section 3.4 equation(3.73). It says that Fourier transform is given by:
$$U(k,t|r_0,t_0)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dr ~.r ~u(r,t|r_0,t_0) ~~e^{-ikr}$$

I am an engineer and have just studied $f(t)$ transform and not $f(r,t)$ Fourier transform, I want to know from where does this come from?
**Further is it possible to have Fourier transform of a function like $f(r,z,t)$ if $r$ is the radius and $z$ is height in cylindrical coordinate system**. If yes what will be the transform equation for this case?
I need it to solve it PDE to a question given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372602/how-to-solve-this-partial-differential-transient-temperature-in-circular-cylind)

Comment: You will need the cylindrical/polar version of the fourier transform known as the Hankel Transform.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_transform

Answer (score 0):

The Fourier Transform is given by the formula $$\mathcal F(f) (k) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-ixk}dx.$$

By the Fourier inversion theorem 
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem)
we can write the inverse of $\mathcal F$ as

$$\mathcal F^{-1}(g)(x) = (2\pi)^{-1}\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(k) e^{ixk}dk.$$

In the case $f$ has two variables $(x_1,x_2)$ we can write the transform with respect to one of the variables as:

$$\mathcal F_{x_1}(f) (k_1,x_2) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x_1,x_2)e^{-ix_1k_1}dx_1.$$

which is just the usual transform keeping one of the variables fixed.

The inverse of $\mathcal F_{x_1}$ is just

$$\mathcal F_{x_1}^{-1}(g)(x_1,x_2) = (2\pi)^{-1}\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(k_1,x_2) e^{ix_1 k_1}dk_1.$$

You can perform the partial Fourier transform described with as many variables as you wish because you are just keeping the other variables fixed.

Comment: Observation: In the case of $f(r,z,t)$ you described, the function with respect to the variable $t$ is periodic and therefore you can take the Fourier series with respect to the variable $t$, keeping the remaining variable fixed. Then the Fourier coefficient will be functions of $r,z$ and you can perform the Fourier transform if you wish.

Comment: I am sorry but a little bit lost now. I have just studied simple transform pair and not proper Fourier analysis. I just know how to do fourier series of $f(t)$. Searching further I got in Folland $$u(x,t)=\sum_{1}^{\infty}b_n e^{-\frac{n^2\pi^2kt}{l^2}} sin\frac{n\pi x}{l}$$ where it is given that $$f(x)=\sum_{1}^{\infty}b_n sin \frac{n\pi x}{l}$$

Comment: Now for two variable may be I need to find $f(x,y)$ so what will be that , can you please give me the equations to me, further you want me to take Fourier transform of $f(x)$ if I am right?